# How to add support for multiple users to edit the same sqlite database?

Tags: database, sqlite, version-control, multi-user

Given a multi-developer project using some sort of version control, and in which one part of the project would include using a desktop application in which the users would add real production data to a sqlite database file, which will then later be used as input/configuration data in an another application. How this file should be distributed between the developers? In version control? On a shared network drive?

You can also switch the sqlite to something else, the only requirement is that it should be embeddable in the desktop application.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit more?

Comment: Sure, is there a specific thing you want clarified?

Comment: Are you asking how to manage the database schema between developers? The data in the database?

Comment: Yes, at least the data, and probably the schema too.

Comment: The users' real data or sample/testing data in the databases?

Comment: Real data. The application needs to be able to add/edit data in the database by multiple users. The database and its data will later be used by a different application as input/configuration data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have distributed uses with local desktop applications, and you want to have them enter and save data into a shared database.

The client desktop applications can simply connect to a database *server* using TCP. You can't use Sqlite for this, as it is a file-based database and not a database server. You could use PostgreSql though.

Other options:

1. local database server on each client computer that synchronizes with master databases or other client databases using replication. Generally speaking, these should all be the same "brand" of database.
2. local file database on each client computer (such as sqlite) that synchronizes with master database or other client databases using a tool like SymmetricDS or Daffodil which lets you sync different databases over HTTP.

Comment: I though of the server solution, but it has other difficulties, for example the overhead of setting it up for each project. I think I'll just go with json file(s), which can be merged.

Comment: You can use a tool like liquibase to make synchronizing the schema and initial easier

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting. I'll have to look into it.